# Wrong link when using "[chat]" in a comment

Tags: support, status-bydesign, chat, hyperlinks

When I use `[chat]` in a comment, the link text says "Parenting Chat" (or whatever the current site name is), but the link just points to https://chat.stackexchange.com, when it should go to the site's main room (in this case, https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/388/parenting)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going to `http://chat.stackexchange.com` *from a specific site* (based on referrer), you're presented with a list of rooms *for that site*, not hopping into one (of possibly many) chat rooms.  This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation -- that wasn't evident. Suggestion: Make the user jump right into the room when there's exactly ONE room for that site.